# My Dashboard in Azure for App Services outage

Tags: azure, kql, azure-dashboard

I am working on a custom Dashboard in Azure. My Application is hosted in an APp Service. If App services is down at Microsoft end, i want to show a Red Dot in my dashboard.

KUSTO will work here?

Some API calls i need to do and some Programming to create dashboard?

Please guide me

Answer (score 0):

You can create the Azure dashboard using template deployment in which Azure offers the ability to orchestrate the deployment of multiple resources.

Once the required resources for Azure Dashboard can be configured in template ARM template format, you can deploy using REST APIs, PowerShell, Azure CLI and Azure Portal template deployment.

This [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/azure-portal-dashboards-create-programmatically#programmatically-create-a-dashboard-from-your-template-using-a-template-deployment) helps you to create the Azure Dashboard using the Sample Templates given.

---

You can enable [Health checks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/monitor-instances-health-check) for your App Service using Azure Monitor App and that you can bring on Azure Dashboard to see your app service is up or down in the form of graph.

Source: [Azure Service Health Dashboard](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/features/service-health/#overview)

---